# Survey 2018 feedback

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

Another year, another survey, another feedback report.

**The good**

This year questions covered many interesting topics and workplace questions, it was easy to flow up and didn't feel odd to answer most if not all of them.

The structure and the way it was organized made sense and the results  (100.000 answers!) are clear, last year it was just 64,000, that means that 40.000 more ***users*** took the survey to the end! kudos.

**The bad**

Both looking at the survey data and remembering the questions, one clear point is that there is quite little difference between amateur devs and professional devs on most (if not all) graphs.

After generating the data, was it necessary to split most features between these two categories given the marginal difference in values?
Maybe other metrics more relevant could have been chosen, I'm not sure.

**The ugly**

This year, again, the SO survey results report forgot about the existence of anything else than [World | USA] in response graph creation, or (in those that weren't [World | USA]) [Top 5 countries without a clear comparison context].

I hope that in future years, citizens from the rest of the world are taken in count and the data is displayed in reference to the socio-economical contexts they belong to, and not just "this place had more responses".

An example would be a 2-level menu between continents, and, inside those, continent averages or top 5 countries. Right now it serves little to no purpose to compare Germany with Canada or India, or to compare World (including USA? excluding USA?) vs. USA, without a wider context.

Answer (score 14):

**The Really Ugly**

Stack Exchange should not be saying that these results are reflective of software developers as a whole. The survey methods alone that they used (convenience sampling) limit their conclusions primarily to users of Stack Overflow who took the survey. That is something that should be made clear in the press releases since the media [reports these survey results](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/03/developers-love-trendy-new-languages-but-earn-more-with-functional-programming/). Once the data has been released it will be possible to do some statistical analysis with it to determine what it can tell you. That could actually a really good opportunity for Stack Exchange to collaborate with universities as well since they have survey methodologists that can help

Of course, in the long run, Stack Exchange really should just hire someone with a strong background in [survey methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_methodology).

Answer (score 12):

> This year, again, the SO survey results report forgot about the
>   existance of anything else than [World | USA] in response graph
>   creation, or (in those that weren't [World | USA]) [Top 5 countries
>   without a clear comparision context].

I agree. As one from the Netherlands, I felt like I got little insight into how others from my country answered. It was mostly just looking at the United States on a giant pedestal of how they responded and their lifestyle and work habits. I think it would be interesting to see what the responses were for all the different countries.

I'm surprised China isn't mentioned in any of the comparisons, considering how they had 3.12% of all responses, while Australia had 1.74%.

Comment: exactly my feelings!

Comment: Well actually its the user reach that's the problem. India also made about 13% contributions.

Answer (score 3):

I am currently performing some custom analysis of the database results with Spark and I find it quite uncomfortable to parse certain columns, specially the ones that reflect integer values as formal text.

IMHO, some columns are too human readable which discourages an easy way of analyzing them automatically. Moreover, considering that the database size is 196MB and has almost 100000 rows, I don't think this results are intended to be used for manual analysis.

I would like to suggest that the database columns are designed in a way that are easier to parse by machines/applications which I think it would encourage extra analyses to be made by our community members.

Find below a few examples that should make my point easier to understand:

================================================================================

- Columns that are easy to transform since they have fixed values.

```
+------------------------+
| JobSatisfaction        |
+------------------------+
| Slightly dissatisfied  |
| Moderately satisfied   |
| Extremely dissatisfied |
| Slightly satisfied     |
+------------------------+
```

I have no problem with this because I can assign fixed integer values to each possible value (Extremely dissatisfied -> 0, Slightly satisfied -> 1, ...)

- Columns that are uncomfortable to deal with since they require removing text, regex matching or other techniques.

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| YearsCodingProf       | Company size            |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| 24-26 years           | 20 to 99 employees      |
| 30 or more years      | Fewer than 10 employees |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

The title of the column makes it clear that the values are years/employees so it is unnecessary to use those terms in the cell values. Additionally you could even create the YearsCodingProfMin, YearsCodingProfMax, CompanySizeMin, CompanySizeMax columns which would contain a single integer value each.

- Columns with excessive information

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FormalEducation                                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Bachelor’s degree (BA, BS, B.Eng., etc.)                                           |
| Master’s degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)                                        |
| Secondary school (e.g. American high school, German Realschule or Gymnasium, etc.) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I understand that when filling the survey the information inside the parenthesis is useful, but at the time of analyzing the results might not. You are delivering the database schema and the survey instruments which already gives a lot of information and context about the possible values of the cells.

================================================================================

These are not meant to be direct suggestions, just example use cases, but I think you could really rethink the database structure for the next survey to allow data analysis frameworks and developers to parse/extract/transform/normalize the data with less effort.

Big data gurus can for sure handle the results better than I do, but the whole point of this is that analyzing the results can be made as easy as possible.

Let's try to make the StackOverflow database the standard example for learning technologies such as Spark and we might even encourage more members to take part in the survey so that we can make the results reflect the current market situation better :-)